# Error while using python's email automation

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, automation, smtplib

I have correctly configured the app password for Gmail which i use for "password". I'm having two-step enabled.
I'm using python 3.8

```
import smtplib
import ssl

email = "send@gmail.com" #changed
password = "aeaeaeaeaeaea" #changed
to = "rece@gmail.com"
msg = "Hello, Python here."

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, ssl.create_default_context())

server.login(email, password)

server.sendmail(email , to , msg)

server.quit()
```

The error I face is

```
C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\cd>python auto_email.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "auto_email.py", line 11, in <module>
    server.login(email, password)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\smtplib.py", line 698, in login
    self.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\smtplib.py", line 605, in ehlo_or_helo_if_needed
    (code, resp) = self.helo()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\smtplib.py", line 434, in helo
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\smtplib.py", line 398, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed

C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\cd>
```

How to overcome this issue? My internet connection is also having a decent speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be an issue with security enhancements Google introduced some years ago. If your GMail account has two-factor authentication enabled (generally a good idea), please try creating an app-specific password and use that in your code. An alternative you might try without two-factor authentication would be to allow "less secure apps". You can find details in the Google documentation here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

UPDATE: Try the following:

```
import smtplib
import ssl

email = "xxx@gmail.com" #changed
password = "rjyofpcoxcdtycip" #changed
to = "yyy@gmail.com"
msg = "Hello, Python here."

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)

server.starttls()

server.login(email, password)

server.sendmail(email , to , msg)

server.quit()
```

It uses STARTTLS for an explicit TLS connection. I successfully tested this using my GMail account with an app password.

Comment: Update:- I even try with turning off two-factors and using less secure apps enabled. Same error occurs

Comment: Thank you for testing. I just updated the answer with a working version of your original code.